# Compile Opengazer-0.1.2 and get vnl_cholesky.h error

Tags: opencv, compilation, computer-vision

After going through so much trouble, I was able to install VXL-1.14.0 and compiled opengazer http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/opengazer/.  I followed its README and a very useful note by mirkrules http://www.mirkules.com/opengazer/vxl_install_notes.txt to modify Makefile of opengazer and relevant files (such as "PointTracker.h").  For example, in my Makefile, I changed the first few lines to be as follows (The vxl headers are in "/usr/local/include/vxl" and shared libraries are in "/usr/local/lib", which has "libvnl_algo.so" and "libvnl.so"):

```
VXLDIR = /usr/local
VERSION = opengazer-0.1.2
CPPFLAGS = -Wall -g -O3
LINKER = -L$(VXLDIR)/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lm -ldl -lvnl -lmvl -lvnl_algo -lvgl -lgthread-2.0 

# change the following line if your vxl library is installed elsewhere
INCLUDES = $(foreach prefix,/usr/local/include $(VXLDIR)/include $(VXLDIR)/include/vxl, \
    $(foreach suffix,/core /vcl /contrib/oxl /core/vnl/algo,-I$(prefix)$(suffix)))
```

===

Still, when I compile, I get error as below:

```
LeastSquares.o: In function `LeastSquares::solve()':
/home/mycomp/Downloads/opengazer-0.1.2/LeastSquares.cpp:27: undefined reference to `vnl_cholesky::vnl_cholesky(vnl_matrix<double> const&, vnl_cholesky::Operation)'
/home/mycomp/Downloads/opengazer-0.1.2/LeastSquares.cpp:27: undefined reference to `vnl_cholesky::solve(vnl_vector<double> const&) const'
LeastSquares.o: In function `~vnl_cholesky':
/usr/local/include/vxl/core/vnl/algo/vnl_cholesky.h:45: undefined reference to `vnl_vector<double>::~vnl_vector()'
/usr/local/include/vxl/core/vnl/algo/vnl_cholesky.h:45: undefined reference to `vnl_matrix<double>::~vnl_matrix()'
LeastSquares.o: In function `LeastSquares::solve(double&, double&, double&)':
/home/mycomp/Downloads/opengazer-0.1.2/LeastSquares.cpp:39: undefined reference to `vnl_vector<double>::~vnl_vector()'
LeastSquares.o: In function `~vnl_cholesky':
/usr/local/include/vxl/core/vnl/algo/vnl_cholesky.h:45: undefined reference to `vnl_matrix<double>::~vnl_matrix()'
/usr/local/include/vxl/core/vnl/algo/vnl_cholesky.h:45: undefined reference to `vnl_vector<double>::~vnl_vector()'
/usr/local/include/vxl/core/vnl/algo/vnl_cholesky.h:45: undefined reference to `vnl_matrix<double>::~vnl_matrix()'
/usr/local/include/vxl/core/vnl/algo/vnl_cholesky.h:45: undefined reference to `vnl_matrix<double>::~vnl_matrix()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opengazer] Error 1
```

Could anyone who is familiar with either VXL, Opengazer or compiling C libraries in general tell me what possibly is going on here?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using an older version of `gcc` seems to solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.4
```

Then change the lines in Makefile that contains `g++` to `g++-4.4`.

Refer to [install notes](http://www.mirkules.com/opengazer/vxl_install_notes.txt) if you get the ambiguous exception problem afterward.